# Batch insert with EclipseLink not working

Tags: database, postgresql, jpa, jdbc, eclipselink

I am using EclipseLink-2.6.1 with Amazon RDS database instance. The following code is used to insert new entities into database:

```
 tx = em.getTransaction();
 tx.begin();
 for (T item : persistCollection) {     
     em.merge(item);               
 }                 
 tx.commit();
```

The object which is being persisted has composite primary key (not a generated one). Locally, queries run super fast, but when inserting into remote DB it is really slow process (~20 times slower). I have tried to implement JDBC batch writing but had no success with it (`eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing` and `rewriteBatchedStatements=true`). When logging queries which are being executed I only see lots of SELECTS and not one INSERT (SELECTS are probably here because objects are detached at first).

My question is how to proceed on this problem? (I would like to have batch writing and then see how the performance changes, but any help is appreciated)

Thank you!

**Edit:**

When using `em.persist(item)` loop is finished almost instantly but after `tx.commit()` there are lots (I guess for every persisted item) queries like :

```
[EL Fine]: sql: ServerSession(925803196) Connection(60187547) SELECT NAME FROM TICKER WHERE (NAME = ?), bind => [AA]
```

My model has `@ManyToOne` relationship with `ticker_name`. Why are there again so many slow SELECT queries?

Comment: merge takes both new and detached instances, it must query the database to determine if an insert or an update is needed, and will only update if there are changes.  If there are selects but no inserts, it is because these are existing, detached items that haven't changed from what is in the database.  If you are sure they are new (or just meant to be new), call persist instead.  The provider doesn't need a select call and instead will batch insert all passed in items.  My guess is you will get an exception though as stated above - these are not new for some reason.

Comment: @Chris I have updated my question with eclipselink log from using persist. Performance did not increase (loop finishes fast but those new SELECT queries are slow)

Comment: Where is this query coming from, as I suspect you have a process triggering the queries on each time somehow.

Comment: Does `rewriteBatchedStatements=true` actually work for Postgres? I think it might be only recognized by a MySQL Driver.